# Codeigniter Form Empty Check on Submit Using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I need to validate while submitting my form without any value with an alert message, 'Your field is empty'.
Please help me anyone.
Thanks

```js
Function load_pagination_content() {
        $('.dt_glo_loader').attr('src', base_url+'images/loading-file/loading.gif');
        $(".dt_glo_loader").show();  
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url("apps/blr/get_blr_pagi"); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#frm_blr_home").serialize(),
        })
        .done(function( respond ) {
            $("#tableBody").html( respond );
            console.log("success");
   
   var myDiv = document.getElementById('scroll_top');
   var intElemScrollTop = myDiv.scrollTop;
   myDiv.scrollTop = 0;
   
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        })
        .always(function() {

   $('.popover-source2').popover();

            $('.dt_glo_loader').attr('src');
            $(".dt_glo_loader").hide(); 
        }); 
    }
```

```html
<form method="post" action="" id="frm_blr_home">
   Court Division :
   <select name="court_division_id" class="court_division_id class-select2 foucus_color" style="width:155px !important" id="court_division_id" />
      <option value=" ">Select Court Division</option>
      <option value="">All</option>
      <?php foreach($court_division->result() as $row){?>
      <option class="foucus_color" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->name; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
   </select>
   &nbsp; Case Type : 
   <?php ?> 
   <select name="case_type_id" style="width:205px !important" class="case_type_id class-select2" id="case_type_id">
      <option value=" ">Select Case Type</option>
      <option value="">All</option>
      <?php foreach($case_type->result() as $row){?>
      <option value="<?php echo  $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->name; ?></option>
      <?php }  ?>
   </select>
   <?php ?> 
   &nbsp;Hon'ble Justice Name : 
   <select name="justice_id" class="justice_id class-select2" style="width:225px !important" id="justice_id">
      <option value=" ">Select Justice Name</option>
      <option value="">All</option>
      <?php foreach($justies_name->result() as $row){?>
      <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->name; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
   </select>
   <input type="hidden" class="mhid" name="mhid" value="<?php echo $mhid; ?>" />
   <input type="hidden" class="cdid" name="cdid" value="<?php echo $cdid; ?>" />
   <input type="hidden" class="pageno" id="pagenoid" name="pageno" value="1" /> 
   <br>
   Case No. : <input type="text" name="case_no" style="width:95px !important;" class="case_no foucus_color" placeholder=" Case No." id="case_no" required value="<?php echo set_value('case_no',''); ?>"/>
   Parties : <input type="text" name="parties" style="width:200px !important;" class="parties foucus_color" placeholder=" Parties" id="" required value="<?php echo set_value('parties',''); ?>"/>
   Section : <input type="text" name="under_section" style="width:95px !important;" class="under_section foucus_color" placeholder=" Section" id="" required value="<?php echo set_value('under_section',''); ?>"/>
   Article : <input type="text" name="article" style="width:95px !important;" class="article foucus_color" placeholder=" Article" id="" required value="<?php echo set_value('article',''); ?>"/>
   Order/Rule : <input type="text" name="order_rule" style="width:95px !important;" class="order_rule foucus_color" placeholder=" Order/Rule" id="" required value="<?php echo set_value('order_rule',''); ?>"/><br>
   Order/Judgment Date : <input type="text" name="judgment_date" style="width:90px !important;" class="judgment_date foucus_color" placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" id="" required value="<?php echo set_value('judgment_date',''); ?>"/>
   Reference : <input type="text" name="short_description" style="width:220px !important;" class="short_description foucus_color" placeholder=" Reference" id="" required value="<?php echo set_value('short_description',''); ?>"/>
   Search by : <input type="text" name="any_words" class="any_words foucus_color" style="width:295px !important;" placeholder=" Any Word, Any Matter, Any Section or Any Sentence" id="any_words" required value="<?php echo set_value('any_words',''); ?>"/>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2" style="padding:0px; margin-left:-30px; width:15%;">
      <h4> 
         <span style="color: #F00;">Total Found&nbsp:&nbsp;<span id="showtotalPage"></span> 
         </span>
      </h4>
      </br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn_middle" id="button_blr_home">Search</button>&nbsp;
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btn_middle" id="case_list2">Clear</button>
      <button type="button" style="display:none;" id="button_blr_home_hidden">Search 2</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the time and provide a more minimal example of what your code is doing. It is amazing how often you will solve the issue yourself by doing that. Also show exactly where you have attempted the checks that you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

try this one.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#frm_blr_home").submit(function(){
        if($("#case_no").val() == ""){
            alert('Your case no is empty.');
            return false;
        }
    });
});

</script>
```